# Accumatia Employee Pay Data Failure

Tags: c#, acumatica

When you using the following code using the Accumatica API for entering emplyee data, I get a sql error.

> "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXDatabaseException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'JWMEmployeeTypeID', table 'atlastechinc.dbo.JWMEmployeeProjectMgmt'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".

Why would I get this error if I am passing in the employee type? My Suspicion is that the Acumatica API is not working correctly and failing to to get the employee type id.

I was expecting the command to save since I had the employee type entered. I have tried reordering the parameters nothing seems to work.

```
WM2010JMContent w = context.WM2010JMGetSchema();

List<Command> cmds2 = new List<Command>();
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.ServiceCommands.NewRow });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.EmployeeInfo.EmployeeID, Value = employee.General.EmployeeID.ToString() });

 
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.EmployeeType, Value = "HRB" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.Currency, Value = "USD" });

cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.NoteText, Value = "USD" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.YearlySalary, Value = "0" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.HourlyRate, Value = "0" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.PayPeriodSalary, Value = "0" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.EffectiveDate, Value = "4/28/2023" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.EffectiveEndDate, Value = "4/28/2026" });

cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.PayPay.ServiceCommands.RowNumber, Value = "-1" });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.Actions.Insert });
cmds2.Add(new AtlasSync.DataSync.Value { LinkedCommand = w.Actions.Save });
var res2 = context.WM2010JMSubmit(cmds2.ToArray());
```

Comment: The database settings is requiring data in field JWMEmployeeTypeID. You code is not adding a value to this property.

Answer (score 0):

If you send the database ID rather than the code (if different) does it work then?

Is the field JWMEmployeeTypeID stored in the database? For example, does it have a PXDBInt rather than a PXInt field?

I assume you built a web service endpoint and are using the WSDL to manipulate these objects. If so, do you have the property name of EmployeeType mapped to the empoyee type screen object? Sometimes if these objects get moved on a screen, the web service endpoint needs to be updated.

Lastly, Acumatica is depreciating the SOAP service, so I would look to migrate to using the REST API and extending a web service endpoint to handle these items.